# Threads performance spikes on Win10 C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, lag

I'm writing my hobby game engine and currently implementing physics. I added multithreading to it and it worked fine on my MacBook until I compiled it on my windows machine. On Win10 sometimes threads can't resolve as fast as usual for no reason and it affects only Windows. It happens consistently around 1-2 times per second. I'm not sure which direction I should move.
That's the typical initialization of the threads:

```
void PhysicsWorld::findCollisions(std::vector<BodyPair> *pairs, CollisionCollector *collisionCollector)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(maxThreads);
    std::vector<BodyPair>::iterator currentPair = pairs->begin();
    int pairsPerThread = pairs->size() / maxThreads;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
    {
        if (i == maxThreads - 1)
            threads.push_back(
                std::thread(_collide, currentPair, pairs->end(), &collisionDispatcher, collisionCollector));
        else
        {
            threads.push_back(
                std::thread(_collide, currentPair, currentPair + pairsPerThread, &collisionDispatcher, collisionCollector));
            currentPair += pairsPerThread;
        }
    }
    OPT_THREAD()
    for (auto &th : threads)
        th.join();
}
```

Here I measure the execution time:

```
void PhysicsWorld::process(float delta)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    deltaAccumulator += delta;
    prepareBodies();
    while (deltaAccumulator > subStep)
    {
        deltaAccumulator -= subStep;

        CollisionCollector collisionCollector;
        std::vector<BodyPair> pairs;

        applyForces();
        findCollisionPairs(&pairs);
        findCollisions(&pairs, &collisionCollector);
        solveSollisions(&collisionCollector);
        finishStep();
    }

    printf("%i\n", std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count());
}
```

Basically all the function calls here use threads by the principle described above. Spikes happen no matter how many objects or calculations do I have. Even if it 10 or 200 objects - they will occur and be visually noticeable even if there is no collisions. I tried to pinpoint the exact function or calculation that may be causing it but had no luck, seams to me the problem is with threads itself.

Also I need to notice that the game code examples without physics are working fine, I have no reasons currently to think that the problem is outside of this specific area. Plus, on windows, before I implemented threads actually physics worked without this lags too, just slow.

Full code you can find here:
https://github.com/seltee/red_ten_engine/blob/master/src/physics/physicsWorld.cpp

The only thing I have figured out to try is to optimize threads for windows exclusively, but it didn't help:

```
#define OPT_THREAD()                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
        int core = 1;                                                       \
        for (auto &th : threads)                                            \
        {                                                                   \
            SetThreadAffinityMask(th.native_handle(), 1 << core);           \
            SetThreadPriority(th.native_handle(), THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST); \
            core++;                                                         \
        }                                                                   \
    }
#else
#define OPT_THREAD() \
    {                \
    }
#endif
```

Comment: you might benefit from using some form of thread pool rather than creating new threads for every task

Comment: It sounds like a solution to try. Thanks.

Comment: Thread creation is "expensive" so as @AlanBirtles says you'd better have a few threads ready for reuse. On windows you can also use `std::async` since its implementation on windows already uses a threadpool.

Comment: Increasing thread priority can be a messy business. It can sometimes result in the OS deprioritizing your process. You must also be careful about owning higher-priority threads if your process itself has a lower priority, as it can be starved-out.

Comment: std::async works so perfectly fine, fps is much higher now and without lags, thank you a lot!

Comment: I assume you are compiling with compiler optimizations enabled, right?